# JAVA - get response from system to the UI

Tags: java, servlets, java-8

I'm new to java and I have servlet which connect to some system and get data, while debug the code I see that I was able to connect and get the data, ( I dont get any error) . I use the following code :

```
    try {
            urlConnection.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String messagePrefix = "Connection error: ";
            LOGGER.error(messagePrefix, e);
        }


OutputStream clientOutStream = responseToClient.getOutputStream();
    copyStream(backendInStream, clientOutStream);
    responseToClient.setStatus(backendResponseCode);

int backendResponseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

InputStream backendInStream = null;
        try {
            if (backendResponseCode < 400) {
                backendInStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String messagePrefix = "Input stream error: ";
            LOGGER.error(messagePrefix, e);
        }
```

Now I have this simple index.html and my question how should I print the data back to the browser ?

( I wasnt able to copy the html file as code :(

[image]

Any idea how to pass the response to the UI , I try to add response tag and put the variable as global without success...

Comment: use JSP to display the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can send the response using dispatcher or httpsession and use jsp to get the response in UI

in your back end simply use

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 

    session.setAttribute("backendresponse",backendresponse))


}
```

and in your jsp you can get and store that data in an arraylist as

```
<%
ArrayList<> list=(ArrayList<>)session.getAttribute("backendresponse");


%>
```

Now you can use this list to populate data in any tag using **<%= %>** as this is equivalent to a print statement as any expression say

```
<%for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{%>
    <%=list.get(i).getData() %>
<%}%>
```

will print the response in your browser

**UPDATE**

in your servlet you can get the parameters as

```
   String url=request.getParameter("url")
    Class obj=new Class(url)
    session.setAttribute("obj",obj);
response.sendredirect("disp.jsp")
```

in your **disp.jsp**

```
 <%
    ArrayList<> list=(ArrayList<>)session.getAttribute("backendresponse");


    %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <%for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {%>
       <h1> <%=list.get(i).getData() %></h1>
    <%}%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont have jsp page should I create one ? I've only index.html that open form that the user can type data...if I need to create on where shuld I do it ? under webapp folder ?

Comment: yes you can create the jsp in webContent folder and copy your html code to that jsp

Comment: ok but this is a mvn project and I dont have webcontent folder just webapp under src->main->webapp , so where should I put it ?

Comment: yes you can keep it there inside webapp->WEB_INF folder :)

Comment: 1. the index.html is under webinf it should be in the same place exactly ?

Comment: can you provide a code sample with my index.html code and the jsp ?

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out and let you know soon

Answer (score 0):

You should have doGet method which has PrintWriter taking each line of the HTML:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: where should I put the data which I got from the system ? see my code

Comment: Does your class extends `HttpServlet`?
Please refer [link] (https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-a-servlet-using-tomcat-server)